# Hide element in specific URL

Tags: javascript, hide

I am struggling to learn some JavaScript and this is my first question here. Please excuse my ignorance. I am asking in desperation.

I have a directory with the following URL: /directory/. When a user wants to add an entry, he is presented with a form which changes the URL to /directory/submit/. Nevertheless, the WordPress page has the same ID. In this page, I have a carousel block which I want to show in the directory but not so, when the form appears. After searching similar user cases, I have implemented the following code:

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('https://mydomain/directory/submit')) {
    //Hide the element.
    document.querySelectorAll('#slick-slider-block-f4fd29c2-f187-44fa-8936-93a65d901a3a')[0].style.display = 'none';
  }
};
```

When I submit this code, I get the following error:

syntax error, unexpected '='

I can sure use some help!

Comment: There can only be one element with that ID or multiple elements with the same class

Comment: There is only one element with that ID.

Comment: What if `indexOf` returns `-1` which is a truthy value?

Comment: Change querySelectorAll to querySelector.

Comment: @Invizi I already have changed it querySelector but I still get the same error.

Comment: @AndriiLukianenko, I am not sure of how I could do that. Would you be kind enough to show me, please?

Comment: You have to first make sure that there actually exists an element with this ID `'#slick-slider-block-f4fd29c2-f187-44fa-8936-93a65d901a3a'`. My guess is that this ID is auto generated and it changes everytime you reload the page. Could you check this first?

Comment: Sure. `indexOf` returns index of the first occurrence (in this case - the first occurrence of the search string in the `href`). But if it's not found, the method returns `-1`. And since only 0 and NaN are falsy numbers, your `if` check will pass with -1.

Comment: If the id always starts with slick-slider-block, you way want to search for id's that start with it. querySelector("[id^='slick-slider-block']") .

Comment: @AndriiLukianenko, unfortunately, there is no change when I placed -1 to if.

Comment: @H.Udara, the ID remains the same when reloading page.

Comment: @Yannis Volos the index issue isn't related to the main problem, just wanted to point it out.

Comment: @Invizi, this is the only id available for this block.

Comment: try `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('#slick-slider-block-f4fd29c2-f187-44fa-8936-93a65d901a3a').length)`. This will tell if there is actually such an element present in the DOM at the time of this code execution. If it returns 0, try running this code after a timeout. Ex: `setTimeout( () => {console.log(document.querySelectorAll('#slick-slider-block-f4fd29c2-f187-44fa-8936-93a65d901a3a').length)}, 5000) // runs after 5 seconds`

Comment: Although, admittedly, this is over my head, if I'm doing it correctly, I get a return of undefined.

Comment: And when I setTimeout, I get 547.

Comment: What happens when you `[0].style.display = 'none';` inside the setTimeout?

Comment: Unsure of the syntax, Should it be like this?
setTimeout( () => {console.log(document.querySelectorAll('#slick-slider-block-f4fd29c2-f187-44fa-8936-93a65d901a3a')[0].style.display = 'none';.length)}, 5000) // runs after 5 seconds